# Django Model Object to Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, python, django

This question was asked a few times before, but I'm unable to get results after following the answers.  I have a Django model.  I convert the model to a JSON string:

```
    from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
    from django.core import serializers
    from .models import MonthData

    #Returns multiple rows
    monthData = MonthData.objects.filter(project=id)
    #Convert models to JSON string
    monthDataStr = serializers.serialize("json", monthData,cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

In my template, I want to convert the JSON string to a Javascript array:

```
var monthData = JSON.parse({{monthData|safe}});
```

However Javascript fails to do the conversion.  The JSON resulting string looks as follows:

```
[  
   {  
      "model":"raidApp.monthdata",
      "pk":3,
      "fields":{  
         "project":1,
         "month":"2017-06-01T00:00:00Z",
         "budgetCost":0.0,
         "forecastCost":385.0,
         "actualCost":0.0,
         "baselineProgress":6.0,
         "plannedProgress":6.0,
         "actualProgress":4.0
      }
   },
   {  
      "model":"raidApp.monthdata",
      "pk":4,
      "fields":{  
         "project":1,
         "month":"2017-07-01T00:00:00Z",
         "budgetCost":261.0,
         "forecastCost":620.0,
         "actualCost":0.0,
         "baselineProgress":11.0,
         "plannedProgress":11.0,
         "actualProgress":8.0
      }
   },
   {  
      "model":"raidApp.monthdata",
      "pk":5,
      "fields":{  
         "project":1,
         "month":"2017-08-01T00:00:00Z",
         "budgetCost":391.0,
         "forecastCost":741.0,
         "actualCost":385.0,
         "baselineProgress":19.0,
         "plannedProgress":19.0,
         "actualProgress":12.0
      }
   },
   {  
      "model":"raidApp.monthdata",
      "pk":6,
      "fields":{  
         "project":1,
         "month":"2017-09-01T00:00:00Z",
         "budgetCost":522.0,
         "forecastCost":868.0,
         "actualCost":500.0,
         "baselineProgress":28.0,
         "plannedProgress":28.0,
         "actualProgress":15.0
      }
   },
   {  
      "model":"raidApp.monthdata",
      "pk":7,
      "fields":{  
         "project":1,
         "month":"2017-10-01T00:00:00Z",
         "budgetCost":652.0,
         "forecastCost":1001.0,
         "actualCost":550.0,
         "baselineProgress":35.0,
         "plannedProgress":34.0,
         "actualProgress":20.0
      }
   },
   {  
      "model":"raidApp.monthdata",
      "pk":8,
      "fields":{  
         "project":1,
         "month":"2017-11-01T00:00:00Z",
         "budgetCost":782.0,
         "forecastCost":1148.0,
         "actualCost":700.0,
         "baselineProgress":40.0,
         "plannedProgress":41.0,
         "actualProgress":25.0
      }
   },
   {  
      "model":"raidApp.monthdata",
      "pk":9,
      "fields":{  
         "project":1,
         "month":"2017-12-01T00:00:00Z",
         "budgetCost":913.0,
         "forecastCost":1275.0,
         "actualCost":800.0,
         "baselineProgress":48.0,
         "plannedProgress":47.0,
         "actualProgress":35.0
      }
   },
   {  
      "model":"raidApp.monthdata",
      "pk":10,
      "fields":{  
         "project":1,
         "month":"2018-01-01T00:00:00Z",
         "budgetCost":1043.0,
         "forecastCost":1408.0,
         "actualCost":900.0,
         "baselineProgress":55.0,
         "plannedProgress":54.0,
         "actualProgress":50.0
      }
   },
   {  
      "model":"raidApp.monthdata",
      "pk":11,
      "fields":{  
         "project":1,
         "month":"2018-02-01T00:00:00Z",
         "budgetCost":1174.0,
         "forecastCost":1500.0,
         "actualCost":1000.0,
         "baselineProgress":60.0,
         "plannedProgress":58.0,
         "actualProgress":52.0
      }
   },
   {  
      "model":"raidApp.monthdata",
      "pk":12,
      "fields":{  
         "project":1,
         "month":"2018-03-01T00:00:00Z",
         "budgetCost":1304.0,
         "forecastCost":1500.0,
         "actualCost":1150.0,
         "baselineProgress":70.0,
         "plannedProgress":67.0,
         "actualProgress":53.0
      }
   },
   {  
      "model":"raidApp.monthdata",
      "pk":13,
      "fields":{  
         "project":1,
         "month":"2018-04-01T00:00:00Z",
         "budgetCost":1396.0,
         "forecastCost":1500.0,
         "actualCost":0.0,
         "baselineProgress":90.0,
         "plannedProgress":85.0,
         "actualProgress":65.0
      }
   },
   {  
      "model":"raidApp.monthdata",
      "pk":14,
      "fields":{  
         "project":1,
         "month":"2018-05-01T00:00:00Z",
         "budgetCost":1500.0,
         "forecastCost":1500.0,
         "actualCost":0.0,
         "baselineProgress":95.0,
         "plannedProgress":90.0,
         "actualProgress":85.0
      }
   },
   {  
      "model":"raidApp.monthdata",
      "pk":15,
      "fields":{  
         "project":1,
         "month":"2018-06-01T00:00:00Z",
         "budgetCost":1500.0,
         "forecastCost":1500.0,
         "actualCost":0.0,
         "baselineProgress":100.0,
         "plannedProgress":100.0,
         "actualProgress":90.0
      }
   },
   {  
      "model":"raidApp.monthdata",
      "pk":16,
      "fields":{  
         "project":1,
         "month":"2018-07-01T00:00:00Z",
         "budgetCost":1500.0,
         "forecastCost":1500.0,
         "actualCost":0.0,
         "baselineProgress":100.0,
         "plannedProgress":100.0,
         "actualProgress":100.0
      }
   },
   {  
      "model":"raidApp.monthdata",
      "pk":17,
      "fields":{  
         "project":1,
         "month":"2018-08-01T00:00:00Z",
         "budgetCost":1500.0,
         "forecastCost":1500.0,
         "actualCost":0.0,
         "baselineProgress":100.0,
         "plannedProgress":100.0,
         "actualProgress":0.0
      }
   }
]
```

Is there a standard way to make a Django model JSON string more "Javascript friendly"?  If not, what workarounds are available?

If what I'm trying to do is not best practice, how can I send Django model data to Javascript without having to send row by row or value by value?

Comment: You'll need to explain how Javascript is "failing" to do the conversion. What happens? What error do you see? But you should also show the rest of the view, as well as the template where you are outputting that JSON so that it can be converted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to get it working.  All I had to do:

```
var monthData = {{monthData|safe}};
```

Somehow JS figures out it is an object without parsing anyting!